# visual studio key binding for c++ and c#

Tags: c#, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am mainly a C# developer, but now I am working a c++ project.
In C# when I right click on a document or a variable or a class definition, I get a lot of menu that help to develop faster (for example refactor to change the name of a variable) but in c++ all of these menus are disabled.

I think, there is a setting that set my environment to c# and hence the menus are not valid for c++. Am I right?

How can I change the setting and make it compatible with c++?

Is there any useful extensions that help me to do these type of things in c++?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this functionality just doesn't exist for C++ like it does for C#. There's nothing wrong with your IDE or its configuration.

You *can* reset Visual Studio's settings to the default C++ development settings if you want, but there's not much point in doing so. It'll just change certain key bindings to be more familiar to people used to Visual C++ 6.0 and you won't be able to find the commands that you want. No new commands will magically appear. To do this, use the Import/Export Settings Wizard, accessible under the Tools menu. All of the default language settings are available as pre-defined options on the "Import" screen.

As far as extensions go, consider Whole Tomato's [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/). You have to pay for it, but it's really an awesome and indispensable tool for C++ developers who use Visual Studio. There are probably other options, but I can't recommend any of them.